# jQuery UI & document.ready in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I have a very large and complex jQuery UI application that is designed to work with Chrome (the other browsers do not matter at this stage). I have noted the following

1. The time required to process all of my customization code under `$(document).ready` is less than 2s.
2. Once doc.ready has been executed the document should be ready for use right?  Not what I observe.  The Chrome tab containing the application continues to show the spinning "doc loading" animation for a good 7s after doc.ready has finished execution.  For good measure I exited doc.ready without doing any application customization.  It made no difference - the 7s spin stays put.  In the mean time the application is completely unresponsive.

I'd be much obliged to anybody who could shed some light on what is going on under the covers that stops the application from being ready. The script base for the application is large - is the delay I am experiencing down to the time that Chrome/V8 requires to compile the script?

Comment: The ready event is triggered before external resources such as images are loaded. So that might take some time. But if the page is not responsive, some expensive JS code could also be the problem.

Comment: I feel inclined to agree with @FelixKling. But would add that JS is interpreted and not compiled so it would not be the problem.

Comment: My understanding is that Chrome **does** compile Javascript http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_(JavaScript_engine). I just ran into  this - http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/02/13/google-speeds-chrome-compiling-javascript-background/#!AneyZ. The beta referred to there is Chrome 33 which is what I see in the Chrome About box.